# android app "MindstormsGamepad" what to do to get the 3rd Motor in action?

Tags: android, nxt, lego-mindstorms

when using the app "MindStormsGamepad" it control 2 motors of NXT (as a car).

does anyone know what to do to control the 3rd motor ? what should I do?

you can take a look at the source code from here

https://code.google.com/p/ohwada/source/browse/#svn%2FMindstormsGamepad

the code seems different from the tutorials on the internet about connecting an android device to the NXT.

any help would be appreciated. thnx

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the program. You can see [here](https://code.google.com/p/ohwada/source/browse/MindstormsGamepad/src/jp/ohwada/android/mindstormsgamepad/util/MindstormsMessage.java#137) that perhaps the author intended to someday add motor A, but has not done it yet.

Here is the linked line since the link will eventually break:

```
//      private int mMotorAction = MOTOR_A;
```

So, the starting place would be to uncomment this line. Then you will need to add functions to tell this motor to actually do something. Finally you will need to create an interface that uses these new functions.

Comment: thanks, but the action of the other motors, wont stop automatically, let's say that the 3rd motor is to rotate 90 degrees only, how to do it ?